# Pull out numerical factors from the argument

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I'm trying to define a function that is distributive over Plus and pulls out the numerical factors from the argument:

```
 {2 a[1] - 3 b[2]*c, c, 8 d*f}//applyF
 = {2F[a[1]]-3 F[b[2]*c],F[c],8F[d*f]}
```

I suspect there's something already implemented in Mathematica to do that easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general linear function:

```
F[arg_Plus] := F /@ arg
F[n_?NumericQ x_] := n F[x]
```

Applied to my example,

```
{2 a[1] - 3 b[2]*c, c, 8 d*f} // Map[F]
```

> {2 F[a[1]] - 3 F[c b[2]], F[c], 8 F[d f]}